# How do I put something in front of an image?

Tags: vb.net, z-index, picturebox

Using VB.net VS2010 and Winforms, I am simply trying to add both a picturebox and a label to a panel, but the label will not go in front of the picture box. How can I set the label as the foremost object? Using the code below, the label always ends up behind the picturebox.

```
 Public Class MyTab

    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Panel
    Public myText As New Label
    Public tab_top_left as New Picturebox

    Public Sub New(ByVal tab_object As tab_properties_object)

        With tab_top_left
            .BackgroundImage = My.Resources.tab_top_left
            .Parent = Me
            .Location = New Point(0, 0)
            .SendToBack()
            .Width = 20
            .Height = 19
            .Name = "tab_top_left"
        End With

        Dim TextString As String = tab_object.top_tab_text

        myText.Font = CustomFont.GetInstance(Main.main_font_size_up3, FontStyle.Regular)
        myText.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0)
        myText.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 204, 204, 204)
        myText.Text = TextString
        myText.Location = New Point(0, 0)
        myText.Width = 200
        myText.Height = 40
        myText.UseCompatibleTextRendering = True
        myText.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
        myText.Name = "tab_" & myText.Text
        myText.Parent = Me
        myText.BringToFront()

        Me.Width = myText.Left + textSize.Width + 15
        Me.Height = 40
        Me.Name = "_" & TextString
        Me.Location = New Point(0, 0)

   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I cant see where you are adding the child controls to the Controls Collection.  BringToFront wont do anything until you do

Comment: As suggested by Plutonix, without a previous .Controls.Add(), BringToFront() doesn't make any sense. You can either add both controls to this class (Me.Controls.Add(myText) & Me.Controls.Add(tab_top_left)) and then use BringToFront() to reorder them. Or even add them to the the main form (otherwise why making the variables public?) and use BringToFront after that.

Comment: I added the code for myText.parent = Me. It was already there in my app, I just missed it when I was cutting and pasting. The top_tab_left already has the code .parent = Me which adds it to the controls.